# OData search on many fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, odata

I have an OData search like so:

```
$.getJSON("/api/job/GetJobs?$orderby=JobDate desc&$top=10&$skip=" + skip + ""
```

Is there a way to search against many fields, i.e. I want to include one filter field OR send multiple filters for each field.

If I can only send one filter should I create a NotMapped property that is a string of all the ones I want to search and filter against this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

**Search for one field with multiple conditions**:

```
http://yoiur_domain.com/api/job/GetJobs?$filter=(field1 eq 'something' OR field1 eq 'another thing')
```

**Search for multiple fields**:

```
http://yoiur_domain.com/api/job/GetJobs?$filter=(field1 eq 'something' OR field2 eq 'another thing')
```

Comment: Thats great, is there a way to use contains or can you only use eq?

Comment: You can use substringof as follow:
http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$filter=substringof('Alfreds', CompanyName) eq true

Comment: If I need to do it against a linked property i.e. 
    substringof('test',Client.Name) eq true
How do I do this as code mentioned doesn't work? EDIT By doesn't work I mean results are returned but no filter was applied